# 301 редирект дирректории в htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, apache, woocommerce

Есть дирректория /shop/
В ней имеются саб-дирректории вида /shop/page/2 /shop/page/3 и тд.

Нужно настроить редирект типа Moved Permanently (301) в корень сайта:
/shop/ > /
/shop/page/2 > /page/2

и т.д.

Сайт на wordpress, можно плагином или напрямую в htaccess.

Comment: Точно имеется [директория](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3_(%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0))? Или просто адреса такого вида? В ВП/WC нет таких директорий.

Comment: все верно, дирректорий нет, это чпу водрпресса

Comment: Тогда.. Если там реальные страницы, то зачем терять клиентов? А если их нет, тогда нужно разбираться почему они появились и что отдают, а не костылить редиректы. Впрочем, если очень хочется - любым сеошным плагином (как без него на ИМе?) можно запретить пагинацию. Ну или в хтацессе.. Манов в сети полно.